# MOSFET Turns on without voltage on the gate?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I am using the following transistor to turn a motor on and off:
http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/418991/INFINEON/IPP096N03LG.html

I am applying 12V to the drain and 0V to the gate... but for some reason current is flowing through and the 12V is coming out the other side. I want the transistor to only come on when I apply a 5v signal to the gate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Image of my circuit]

Comment: Didn't it occur to you that we might want to see the circuit?

Comment: Sorry I added one

Comment: You're not applying 0V to the gate. If the transistor were fully on, the gate would be near 12V.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have chosen an excellent MOSFET, but your circuit is incorrect as shown.
If this is how it is actually connected it will not work.

[A better datasheet for your IPP096N03L MOSFET is here](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/IPP096N03L_rev1.02.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b408e8c90004&fileId=db3a304412b407950112b4273c3b[3bdf)

A MOSFET requires a control voltage to be applied between gate and source.
 In the case of an N Channel MOSFET the gate must be more +ve than the source.  In this case +4V to +5V n the gate will work well.

While your circuit is incorrect it does not explain what you are seeing. I suspect you may have drain and source reversed (or worse :-) ).
Place FET on a table, label side up, pins towards you.
 Left side pin = gate.
 Right side pin = source.
 Middle pin (if present) and tab = Drain.

BUT - When the motor is on the source will be at 12V so the gate needs to be at 12+4 = 16V.

SO - The motor should be in the DRAIN of the MOSFET and not in the source. 
The gate level also MUST be controlled at all times.

**This is the original incorrect circuit** with required changes shown:

[image]

---

**Correct circuit.**

Ensure pinout is correct as above.
 Then:

- Remove motor from source
- Connect source to ground
- Connect motor from 12V to drain.
- Connect diode across motor as shown now.
- Consider connecting an eg 10k resistor gate to ground to ensure gate is grounded if drive is ever disconnected.

Drive with 0v/5V.
 If this does not work the MOSFET is dead.

Your circuit will look more like this.

- ZD1 is optional but useful for inductive loads (such as a motor). zener voltage should be higher than max drive voltage. Say a 12V zener. Optional.
- R1 is not strictly necessary when playing. Say 10 ohms.
- TTL gate shown here is replaced by a microcontroller in your case.
- Note that this circuit works well for slow switching (maybe 10's to hundreds of Hz) but for higher switching speeds yu will need a gate driver. Simple and cheap to do but necessary at say 1 kHz up.

[image]

Comment: I choose a transistor that you recommended.  I understand a lot more but still am not all the way there :/

Comment: @DaveC - Build it as in the bottom circuit and it WILL work :-).